# Oracle apex create read only breadcrumb entry

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I want to create a breadcrumb when one of the entries is shown but not clickable.

for example:

```
page1 \ page2 \ page3 \ page4
```

page1 and page3 are clickable but page2 is not (page4 is the current page).

Defining the breadcrumb entry's target as "No target" keeps it clickable (redirect to the same page)
[image]

so this solution not good enough for me.

Apex version is 19.1.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the page where you have the breadcrumbs rendered, you could remove the href using jquery.
In the page attributes > execute when page loads, put:

```
$('a.t-Breadcrumb-label').filter(function(){
    return this.innerHTML == 'page2'; 
}).removeAttr("href");
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping for an apex built-in solution but I guess that's good enough